# Data Structures in C - HeapSort - Weird Issue

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures, gdb, heapsort

so basically I'm trying to implement a heapsorting algorithm in C, I always use a `sentinel node` at `arr[0]`, keep that in mind. I'm having a weird bug, where it gets sorted correctly, but always one element in the array is transformed into a huge value for some reason, please tell me why.

*PS: I would really like if you could guide me how to find the bug using `gdb`*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void 
swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void
heapify(int arr[], unsigned int size, unsigned int parent)
{

    unsigned int child;
    int temp;

    for(temp=arr[parent]; parent*2<=size; parent=child)
    {
        child = parent*2;
        if(child!=size && arr[child+1]>arr[child])
        {
            child++;
        }
        if(temp<arr[child])
        {
            arr[parent] = arr[child]; 
        }
        else{break;}
    }

    arr[parent] = temp;
    

}

void
heapsort(int arr[], unsigned int size)
{

    int i = 0;

    for(i = size/2; i>0; i--)
    {
        heapify(arr, size, i);
    }

    for(i = (size-1); i>0; i--)
    {
        swap(&arr[1],&arr[i]);
        heapify(arr,i-1,1);
    }

}

int main()
{

    int test[] = {0,8,2,4,7,9,3,6,5};
    unsigned int size = sizeof(test)/sizeof(test[0]);

    heapsort(test,size);

    for(unsigned int i = 1; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", test[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
32766
```

Once again, I use a `sentinel node` so the 0 isn't displayed, in this scenario, the `2` is transformed into `32766` and I have no idea why, sometimes if I change values it can happen to any element in the array at any position for any value.

Comment: *guide me how to find the bug using gdb*. You have the right idea there in wanting to use a debugger. But Stack Overflow is not well suited to such tutorial style guidance. Best to search for a basic tutorial. Should only take a few minutes to get started. High level: Start the program in gdb. Use `b` command to add breakpoints where you want the code to stop to examine it. Use `s` to run the code one step at a time. Use `p` to print out variables.

Comment: That's what I've been doing, but I can't seem to find the bug... Also, why use `b` if I can use `n` or `s` instead ?

Comment: `b` is to add breakpoints. For any real sized program you may not want to run the code one line at a time as that would take forever. General technique is to build up the code by writing, testing and debugging small components at a time. Once you are sure certain components/sections of the code are correct you don't need to step through those one line at a time but rather let the program run until it reaches a point in the code that you do want to examine.

Comment: So I can execute multiple `run`s in one go ? so that the next `run` will execute the code and stop at my next defined `b`, correct?

Comment: Yes correct. Also, may I ask why you have a sentinel node? It doesn't seem to serve any purpose and instead just complicates the code for little or no benefit.

Comment: It's for purposes like base case, the smallest value.

Comment: Running the `watch child` command when you’re inside the function `heapify` may help. You want to make sure that all accesses to `arr` are within  bounds.